# How to print xml data like this?

Tags: xml, perl

I have XMl file like this

```
 <orderinfo>
 <data>
  <Id>raj</Id> 
  <Customer>bvr</Customer> 
  <Suppliers>
   <Supplier Id="svr" /> 
   <Supplier Id="dvr" /> 
 <Supplier Id="klr" /> 
 </Suppliers>
 </data>

 <data>
  <Id>svr</Id> 
  <Customer>raj</Customer> 
  <Suppliers>
    <Supplier Id="avr" /> 
    <Supplier Id="csr" /> 
    <Supplier Id="ksr" /> 
  </Suppliers>
</data>

<data>
  <Id>avr</Id> 
  <Customer>svr</Customer> 
  <Suppliers>
    <Supplier Id="Bpv" /> 
    <Supplier Id="Wrr" /> 
    <Supplier Id="Sdr" /> 
  </Suppliers>
</data>

<data>
  <Id>csr</Id> 
  <Customer>svr</Customer> 
  <Suppliers>
   <Supplier Id="bvs"  /> 
   <Supplier Id="vvs" /> 
   <Supplier Id="Ssv" /> 
  </Suppliers>
 </data>

 <data>
   <Id>klr</Id> 
   <Customer>PUMC</Customer> 
   <Suppliers>
     <Supplier Id="ssn" /> 
     <Supplier Id="qis" /> 
     <Supplier Id="nan" /> 
    </Suppliers>
 </data>
</orderinfo>
```

above xml reprents the supplier customer relationship.I need to search The customer tag data is not equal to Id tag of any data node then that customer is the top customer.
if we found top customer then print that node Id and then that node Suppliers Id. based on each suppliers Id of this node, I need to match This supplier Id is matched with 
any Id tag of all nodes, if match found print that node supplier Id's. if no matches found just leave that supplier Id. I need to reapeat same procedure like that then I 
will get relation between top customer to bottom supplier.

In the above XML data i need to print like this

```
                                   bvr

                                   raj
                   svr             dvr          klr
      avr          csr      ksr   (empty)   ssn  qis nan
 (bpv wrr sdr) (bvs vvs ssv)
```

here "bvr" is the top customer because its not equal to any Id tag of data nodes. then print this is top customer.next print that node Id and that node Suppliers id's.
now strat with using this suppliers Id's , match each supplier Id is equal to any Id tag of data nodes, in this example "supplier Id="svr"" is equal to second data node "Id"
then print that supplier Id's. then go and search the same procedure for remaing suppliers Id's of top custormer. in this example second supplier Id "dvr"is not matched with any 
data node Id so just print that one. third supplier Id is matched with last data node Id so print last data supplier Id's. then now go for "svr supplier Id's do same procedure.

Just I shown the in graph representation form for understanding. How can I print this tag elements data like that.
please help me someone because I am very beginner.Its very complicated for me.

Comment: Your "XML" is not valid. XML requires a root element.

Comment: So the problem breaks down into two sections. 1/ Turn the XML into a suitable tree of nodes. 2/ Turn that tree into some kind of graphic representation. Where, exactly, are you stuck? What do you have so far?

Comment: @help me with convert xml to tree of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) to parse your XML and convert it into DOM tree. See example below that loads your example and print values of `Id` tags:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom  = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'filename.xml');
my $root = $dom->documentElement();
for my $data ($root->findnodes('data')) {
    print $data->findvalue('Id'), "\n";
}
```

Look into [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode) and [XML::LibXML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aElement) for available methods to access data and traversal.